# Python module' object is not callable

Tags: python

This is a python rooky question...
The file structure is like that

```
./part/__init__.py
./part/Part.py
./__init__.py
./testCreation.py
```

when running python3 testCreation.py I get a

```
part = Part() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

no complain about import. so I wonder what the issue is !?

also coming from Java, can some one comment if organising classes for python is better just in packages with subpaths or in modules (ommit the **init**.py file) ?

Comment: `Part` is a module, not a class.

Comment: You probably want `from part.Part import Part`, but a [mcve] would help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python, you need to distinguish between *module names* and *class names*. In your case, you have a module named `Part` and (presumable) a class named `Part` within that module. You can now use this class in another module by importing it in two possible ways:

1. Importing the entire module:

   ```
    import Part

    part = Part.Part()  # <- The first Part is the module "Part", the second the class
   ```
2. Import just the class from that module into your local (module) scope:

   ```
    from Part import Part
    part = Part()  # <- Here, "Part" refers to the class "Part"
   ```

Note that by convention, in Python modules are usually named in lowercase (for instance `part`), and only classes are named in UpperCamelCase. This is also defined in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), the standardized coding style guide for Python.

Comment: Thanks for adding the hints to standards also !

Comment: _UpperCamelCase_ has another name: PascalCase