# Why i cant call the class?

Tags: python

This is the main class:

```
import Orange


def mainn():
    orange = Orange()
    print(orange.color)
```

The IDE is giving me this message  `'Orange' is not callable.`

And this the `Orange` class:

```
class Orange:
    def __init__(self, color, weight):
        self.color = color
        self.weight = weight

    def printorange(self):
        print(self.weight)
        print(self.color)
```

Comment: `import` is meant for packages/modules. What file is `Orange` in? If it’s in `orange.py`, you can do something like `from orange import Orange`.

Comment: Your ```__init__``` method has no default parameters for ```color``` and ```weight```. When you call ```Orange()```, you need to provide values for them.

Comment: @bfontaine: Given that the `import` succeeds, the file is definitely `Orange.py` (which violates PEP8 naming rules, but beginners make this mistake all the time).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384205/python-module-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Orange` is presumably your module name containing the class. You either need to do:

```
 orange = Orange.Orange()
```

or you need to change the import to:

```
 from Orange import Orange
```

If you're coming from a Java background, this may seem odd (since Java classes *are* the "module" there), but in Python, a module name and the class(es) (or lack thereof) defined within said module have nothing to do with one another; you could name the module `Orange.py` and define class `Apple` in it, and Python's fine with that, you just need to import it correctly and ask for the correct name within it.

Note that your code will still fail when you do this, because you neglected to provide the necessary arguments to the `Orange` initializer. You'll need to provide them (or define defaults for `__init__`'s arguments).